# Securing Mercurial repositories hosted in IIS

Tags: mercurial

I've got several Mercurial repositories being hosted with HgWebDir.cgi. It is running in IIS, but it is not using Active Directory.

Right now there are no restrictions on any of the repositories. Anyone can push and pull from any of the repos. I'd like to have user level security where users are only allowed to see their repositories.

I've seen instructions on how to do this with Apache. I've seen instructions on how to do this with Active Directory. But I can't figure out how to do it in my configuration.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the website in IIS Manager.
2. Click “Content View” in the window bottom.
3. Right click HgWebDir.cgi and choose “Switch to Features View”
4. Click “Authorization Rules”
5. Remove any inherited rules
6. Click “Add Allow Rule”
7. Mark “Specified specified users” and add your usernames.